# webview with javaFX

Tags: javafx, webview

hi every one i am trying to get to web application exist in my computer through java fx web view :

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    WebView webView = new WebView();
    WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();

    engine.load("172.0.0.0://HOWEB/documentation:8080");//loadContent("<html> href = C:/Users/kaisios/Desktop/attempt9000.html<\\html>");

    VBox vBox = new VBox();
    vBox.getChildren().addAll(webView);

    Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 800, 500);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

but it does not load the content .
NOTE: I have already run xamp server but i think the formula of the url is wrong

Answer (score 3):

There are several things wrong with the URL:

- The protocol: This is probably `http`. You need to specify the IP in the protocol part of the url instead
- The loopback IP is `127.0.0.1` not `172.0.0.0`
- The port is specified right after the host, which in this case is the IP
- The port may be incorrect (verify in your xampp control panel that the port used is indeed `8080`)

the correct url (assuming the rest is correct; use your standard webbrowser to check first) is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/HOWEB/documentation
```

---

You could also use a file URL, if you don't want to run a server:

```
File file = new File("C:/Users/kaisios/Desktop/attempt9000.html");
engine.load(file.toURI().toString());
```

---

Listening to the `onError` event can help you identify the issue:

```
engine.setOnError(evt -> {
    Throwable error = evt.getError();
    if (error != null) {
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```